# Xcode generating release statements in project converted to ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I just converted a project to ARC using the refactor commands in Xcode. However, when I drag a line from a view in IB to my source code to generate stub ivar code, it is generating code in -viewDidUnload and -dealloc with releases. It obviously does not do this in projects that started out as ARC.

What can I do to the project to stop if from generating non-ARC code?

Comment: Try and restart Xcode. Sounds stupid, but a lot of the time, a restart solves the weirdest things.